# Does it keep the message in RabbitMq when the consumer reads it?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

It is possible in RabbitMq, I am using MassTransit to consume messages
messages to be retained?
I will consume a message, and through it I will make a search and depending on the result I want to delete it or not, is it possible to do that?

I want to know if it is possible to read a message and not remove it in RabbitMq, so that I can read it a second or third time.

Comment: What if you just resend after processing?

Comment: I can't resend it, because the system that sends it is a payment system, I want to keep the message to validate if this payment was paid or not. I don't know if it's right to do that

Comment: Have a separate queue for "messages that need to be revalidated". Control it exclusively. Idea to keep a message on a queue is a bad idea.

Comment: You could just nack/reject it, and tell the broker to requeue it.